# Spring Boot : how auto configure works and @JsonTest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-autoconfiguration

I've read some stuff about how auto-configuration works behind the scene (configuration classes with `@Conditional`, `spring.factories` inside `/META-INF` etc...)

Now I'm trying to understand with an example : `@JsonTest`

I can see this annotation is annotated with things like `@AutoConfigureJson`

What this `@AutoConfigureJson` does exactly ? Does it import some configuration classes with beans inside ? How Spring know how to use this annotation (basically this annotation is almost empty and doesn't say which classes to scan)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@AutoConfigure...` (like @AutoConfigureJson) annotations are the way to allow tests with multiple "slices".

Slices load into your tests only a subset of the application, making them run faster. Let's say you need to test a component that uses the Jackson Object Mapper, then you would need the `@JsonTest` slice. (here is the list of [all available slices](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-test-auto-configuration.html).)

But you may also need some other part of the framework in your test not just tha single slice; let's say the JPA layer. You may want to annotate the test with both @JsonTest and @DataJpaTest to load both slices. [According to the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-tests), this is not supported.

What you should do instead is choose one of the`@...Test` annotation, and include the other with an `@AutoConfigure...` annotation.

```java
@JsonTest
@AutoConfigureDataJpa
class MyTests {
// tests
}
```

**Update**:
at a certain point while evaluating the annotation, Spring Boot will hit [this line](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/4a74521174795d8e2f35d785d99167f89ea3a274/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/ImportAutoConfigurationImportSelector.java#L97) and will pass to the method `SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactoryNames()` a source, that is the fully qualified name of the annotation (like `interface org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.json.AutoConfigureJson` for example).

The [loadFactoryNames method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/b9a612b6374163a1cc891f4f16e61937c3fef0bc/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/io/support/SpringFactoriesLoader.java#L126) will do its magic and read the necessary information [from here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories).

If more details are needed, the best thing is to use a debugger and just follow along all the steps.

Comment: Ok thank you. But I'm interested about how things work behind the scene. I mean : using @AutoConfigure... is likely to import some classes and beans. How does this work ? How does Spring know which beans or config classes to import ?

Comment: Ok, I have added some more details about that.